# logistic regression what does this mean? Then a link function must be used to reverse the logarithm transformation, exponentiating the modeled value

Tags: regression, logistic

Can you offer any assistance on clarifying the meaning of the following content - specifically the section on "Then a link function must be used to reverse the logarithm transformation, exponentiating the modeled value."  This analysis is logistic regression and analyzed in SPSS. Also, how are beta coefficients best defined?

The probability is modeled by taking the log of the odds ratio,

Ln (p/1-p) = B0 + B1X1

The model results in estimated Beta coefficients  B0 + B1X1. Then a link function must be used to reverse the logarithm transformation, exponentiating the modeled value. The result provides the model predicted probability of dropout (or transfer) and the change in model predicted probability if the person received counseling or PTSD diagnosis.

Comment: Note that you need extra parentheses or other brackets on the left-hand side of your equation.

Answer (score 2):

In your original model you have 
$$
\ln [p / (1-p)] = B_0 + B_1X_1
$$
so if there is a unit change in $X_1$ then it will change the left hand side by $B_1$ units. This is hard to interpret. So if you exponentiate $B_1$ you will get $\exp(B_1)$ which is the amount that $p/(1-p)$ is multiplied by. Since $p/(1-p)$ is usually called the odds this results in $\exp(B_1)$ being called the odds ratio. So now we know that a unit change in the predictor variable multiplies the odds by the quantity we calculated. I assume from the rest of what you quote that $X_1$ only has two values so this odds ratio is the change in odds for one category compared to the other.